# getting error while trying to use CASE WHEN THEN in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to use CASE-WHEN-THEN in HQL query but getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: case near line 1, 
   column 387
```

The query part for CASE:

```
" and case hp.Type when 8 then ( " + str1 + ") else " +
                                    " ( " + str2 + " ) end " );
```

This is in the where clause.
Basically, I want to get str1 string in my query when hp.Type is 8 else get str2 string in my query.

Comment: Could you please show full query, your problem can lay in other part of the query.

Comment: @SternK The query was working earlier fine. I got this error only after adding this part.